# Port C Project from Windows to Linux

Tags: c, linux, windows, porting

I am tasked with porting a massive c project from windows to linux. I have never ported anything over to linux before and am pretty new to linux. The project uses quite a bit of win32 calls. I have looked through some of it and understand what those parts do, however there are many moving parts and i feel it would take too much time to look through it all. What would be the best way to port it over? Is it foolish of me to think I can move the project over to the linux machine and work through the errors one by one?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: The easiest approach would be run the Windows binary under Wine, instead of porting the source. There's not always a one-to-one correspondence between Win32 functions and POSIX functions and porting can potentially involve big redesigns of your program structure and logic.

Answer (score 2):

[Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) is a Windows Emulator for Linux, more exactly a re-implementation of the Windows API and binary interface, mainly for Unix-like OSes. It has also a builtin library named *libwine*, which is essentially a compatibility layer between the relevant Linux APIs (mainly: libc and X11) and the Win32.

Compiling the project with libwine, you will compile a Linux executable (binary), using the libwine as a shared lib (shared lib == dll). On this way, you can use the Windows API calls in a Linux project.

Your knowledge of the Win32 API helps a lot, most likely the compatibility isn't 100%. Probably you will have to modify the code a little bit (but not too much).

Comment: Wine = Wine Is Not Emulator  :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks, post extended.